# If $U$ and $V$ have the same dimension, then $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$. If $U$ and $V$ have the same dimension, then $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic.

---

Ok I have started my proof as such:

Let $P = \{u_1, ..., u_d\}$ and $Q = \{v_1, ..., v_d\}$ be bases of $U$ and $V$ respectively. Define the linear transformation $T:U\to V$ by $T(u_i) = v_i$ for $i=1,...,d$. Then we know $U$ and $V$ are isomorphic if $T$ is a bijection.

But here is where I get stuck, how do I show $T$ is a bijection?

Comment: @Shalop, Hi, I am just curious - expressing $Tu=0$ implies $u\in{\rm Ker}(T)$, thus ${\rm Ker}(T) = \{0\}$, so ${\rm null}(T) = 0$ thus $T$ is injective. Then by the rank and nullity theorem we find that ${\rm Rank}(T) = \dim{(V)}$, so $T$ is surjective. Is this satisfactory too?

Comment: Yes. $Tu=0$ implies $u=0$, thus $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ and either you use the rank-nullity theorem, or prove surjectivity directly: a given $v\in V$ can be expressed by basis elements of $Q$, and use the same coeffiecients for the corresponding vector in $U$.

Comment: @Berci, how do we know $Tu = 0$ implies $u=0$?

Comment: Something pedantic that will nevertheless increase your understanding: you haven't actually defined $T$. You've said what $T$ does to each $u_i$. But what is say $T(2u_1)$? $T(u_2+u_3)$? $T$ applied to a general element of $U$?

Comment: A general comment: one way to show that a function is a bijection is to show that it is invertible.

Comment: @user2850514 which book are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:- Use the classification theorem or the theorem which tells that any finite dimensional vector space over the field $F$ is isomorphic to  $\Bbb{F^n}$